# IOError Stream close when i'm using spring shell

Tags: java.util.scanner, spring-shell

When I use my application with Scanner() I received error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
shell:>2023-06-29T11:44:27.476+03:00 ERROR 20520 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readCharacter(BindingReader.java:169) ~[jline-3.23.0.jar:na]
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(BindingReader.java:109) ~[jline-3.23.0.jar:na]
    at org.jline.keymap.BindingReader.readBinding(BindingReader.java:61) ~[jline-3.23.0.jar:na]
```

I unsuccessfully trying to find this error.

In my case i found it. This IOError was caused by `scanner.close()`. After deleting this call, shell works again